# i have changed some settings in BIOS,like i disabled boot options,now my system is turning off immediatly

Tags: windows-8, boot, bios, uefi, poweroff

i have changed BIOS settings,like disabled boot options,disabled,i have disabled boot settings,now my system turning off immediately without showing anything on the screen,,how should i enter into BIOS without turning off the system !!!

Comment: Why can't you turn your system off?

Answer (score 0):

Try holding down the hotkey <kbd>F12</kbd> that opens setup. It should start, usually it is <kbd>f2</kbd>. But try all of them until it works.

Then restore all settings to factory default! Solved!

Answer (score 0):

Try Reseting your BIOS.

Open up your machine and look for the Circle Battery. This is your CMOS Battery.
Remove it (Normally slides or pulls out) and leave it out for around 5 minutes.

Put the battery back in and boot your machine.

Your BIOS settings have now been reset along with your internal clock.